# why my data is add in two tables instead of one table in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes they are name Good and Category.but I have a so weird problem . in fact, when I submit my form to controller for adding good entity.one record add in good and one record add in category but i don't want to add any data in category. my controller get three argument good entity and `HttpPostedFileBase file, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files`

```
  public class Good
    {
        public Good()
        {
            Images = new List<ImageList>();
            Category = new Category();
        }


        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام کالا")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام تصویر")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string LargeImageName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام لاتین")]
        public string EnglishName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "قیمت")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "توضیح مختصر")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "کلمات کلیدی")]
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تعداد بازدید")]
        public int PageVisit { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "وضعیت")]
        public Boolean Status { get; set; }
        //Fk

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ImageList> Images { get; set; }

    }
```

===============

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام مجموعه")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام انگلیسی مجموعه")]
        public string EnglishName { get; set; }


        //navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Good> Good { get; set; }

    }
```

=============================

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductId,Name,ImageName,LargeImageName,EnglishName,Price,ShortDescription,Keyword,PageVisit,Status,CategoryId")] Good good, HttpPostedFileBase file, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    var checkSizeImage = ImageBuilder.Current.LoadImageInfo(file, null);
                    var setting = new ResizeSettings
                    {
                        MaxWidth = 600,
                        MaxHeight = 300,
                        Format = "jpg,png"
                    };


                    var path = Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/Images/GoodGallery/");
                    versions.Add("_small", "maxwidth=270&maxheight=180&format=jpg");
                    versions.Add("_large", "maxwidth=600&maxheight=400&format=jpg");



                    foreach (var suffix in versions.Keys)
                    {
                        file.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file.InputStream, path + file.FileName + suffix, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true));
                    }


                    //good. = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    var dotPosition = file.FileName.IndexOf('.');
                    var largeFileName = file.FileName.Insert(dotPosition, ".jpg_large");
                    var fileName = file.FileName.Insert(dotPosition, ".jpg_small");
                    good.LargeImageName = largeFileName;
                    good.ImageName = fileName;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                good.LargeImageName = "No_Image.png";
                good.ImageName = "No_Image.png";
            }
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file2 in files)
                {
                    if (file2 != null && file2.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                        var path = Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/Images/GoodGallery/");
                        versions.Add("_small", "maxwidth=270&maxheight=180&format=jpg");
                        versions.Add("_large", "maxwidth=600&maxheight=400&format=jpg");
                        foreach (var suffix in versions.Keys)
                        {
                            file2.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file2.InputStream, path + file2.FileName + suffix, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true));
                        }

                        var dotPosition = file2.FileName.IndexOf('.');
                        var largeFileName = file2.FileName.Insert(dotPosition, ".jpg_large");
                        var smallfileName = file2.FileName.Insert(dotPosition, ".jpg_small");
                        good.Images.Add(new ImageList { LargeImageName = largeFileName, SmallImageName = smallfileName });


                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                good.Images.Add(new ImageList { LargeImageName = "No_Image.png", SmallImageName = "No_Image.png" });
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "فایل با موفقیت آپلود شد.";
        }

        db.Goods.Add(good);
        db.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName", good.CategoryId);
        return View(good);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have `Category = new Category();` in your `Good` class constructor.

Comment: if I remove it.I will get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in another part of my project how to solve it.

Comment: Well at that place you have to create Category object. Create object only when you need it, so in this case you need to explicitly create Category object in the another part of your project.

Answer (score 1):

As Good has a property called category and you have already implemented category class like that and made a foreign key thats why.implement in different way or Foreign key implementation in entity framework is like that -- if you dont want the inserting of the row , you should stop foriegn key

please check design , you can go through https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/01/16/that-annoying-insert-problem-getting-data-into-the-db-using-dapper

Comment: if I remove it.I will get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in another part of my project how to solve it.